# Ninject: More than one matching bindings are available same class twice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, ninject, ninject-conventions

Given this class:

```
public class UserQueryHandler : 
    IQueryHandler<UserCredentialsByUsernameQuery, UserJWTIdentity>,
    IQueryHandlerAsync<UserRoleByUserNameQuery, UserRole>
{
```

//..implementation
}

```
public interface IQueryHandler<TParameter, TResult>
{
    TResult Retrieve(TParameter query);
}
public interface IQueryHandlerAsync<TParameter, TResult>
{
    Task<TResult> RetrieveAsync(TParameter query);
}
```

And the following Ninject configuration:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
       .FromThisAssembly()
       .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
       .BindAllInterfaces());

            kernel.Bind(x => x
             .FromThisAssembly()
             .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom(typeof(IQueryHandlerAsync<,>))
             .BindAllInterfaces());
```

I'm getting the following error:

> More than one matching bindings are available.
>
> Matching bindings:
>
> 1) binding from IQueryHandlerAsync{UserRoleByUserNameQuery,
>   UserRole} to UserQueryHandler
>
> 2) binding from IQueryHandlerAsync{UserRoleByUserNameQuery,
>   UserRole} to UserQueryHandler
>
> Activation path:
>
> 1) Request for IQueryHandlerAsync{UserRoleByUserNameQuery, UserRole}

When trying to get an instance using this:

```
var handler = _kernel.Get<IQueryHandlerAsync<UserRoleByUserNameQuery, UserRole>>();
```

The suspicious thing is that I don't get the error trying to instantiate the other interface implementation:

```
var handler = _kernel.Get<IQueryHandler<UserCredentialsByUsernameQuery, UserJWTIdentity>>();
```

And the error disapears if I create a separated class that implements only that interface:

```
public class UserQueryHandler2 : 
    IQueryHandlerAsync<UserRoleByUserNameQuery, UserRole>
{
//..implementation works fine!! }
```

From what I understand, the class is being binded twice, but I don't understand why is this happening (probably a bug?)

Answer (score 0):

`BindAllInterfaces` is binding all the interfaces the type inherits from, which in the case of `UserQueryHandler` is both `IQueryHandler` and `IQueryHandlerAsync`. So your type is being bound to `IQueryHandlerAsync` in the first portion of your Ninject configuration when it's scanning for all types that inherit from `IQueryHandler`.

Comment: Why does it work when I request IQueryHandler<,>? (To understand the issue). How should I configure ninject for these bindings to work? BindToSelf() maybe?